# How to add a skin engine to asp.net MVC system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, skins, wordpress-theming

I'm implementing a solution in ASP.NET MVC that later can be applied to couple of other fields. To do so it will require to re-brand the UI even though the underlying business logic wont need to change. I'd like to write the code in such a way that will allow other developers to only develop code that will only changes the UI. This is similar to the way that themes can be written against Wordpress Blog software.

Can any one suggest how to organize my project to make such feature work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would not use bult in Themes (not actually sure if these still exist in MVC) But you could multiple sets of CSS (with related images) in a Themes folder with a separate path per theme eg: Themes\Default, Themes\Classic, etc where the only configuration is the Path element. This would split the styling from the core code and you would'nt need to use any Theme "Engines" etc.

In your MasterPages/Pages/Views you could just set the path to the stylesheets dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using MasterPages?

Comment: MasterPages don't quite cut it.